# Phone not entering system recovery, adb, fastboot

Tags: firefox-os, fastboot

I flashed a wrong base image binary(flame)(http://1drv.ms/1rCB954) on my ZTE OPEN device. Now its stuck on the main Firefox screen and refuses to enter recovery. It doesn't detect in adb, fastboot either. Is there a way to still recover my phone ?

```
sudo ./flash.sh 
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
roamer2 device

Partition table...
< waiting for device >
sending 'partition' (33 KB)...
OKAY [  0.005s]
writing 'partition'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.007s
Flash nCPU...
sending 'modem' (32369 KB)...
OKAY [  2.963s]
writing 'modem'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 2.965s
sending 'rpm' (143 KB)...
OKAY [  0.014s]
writing 'rpm'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.017s
sending 'tz' (331 KB)...
OKAY [  0.033s]
writing 'tz'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.035s
sending 'sbl1' (239 KB)...
OKAY [  0.023s]
writing 'sbl1'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.025s
sending 'sdi' (10 KB)...
OKAY [  0.002s]
writing 'sdi'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.005s
sending 'fsg' (829 KB)...
OKAY [  0.079s]
writing 'fsg'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.082s
Flash Apps...
sending 'aboot' (354 KB)...
OKAY [  0.034s]
writing 'aboot'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 0.037s
sending 'boot' (7514 KB)...
OKAY [  0.686s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  1.290s]
Finished. total time: 1.976s
sending 'system' (267069 KB)...
FAILED (remote: data too large)
Finished. total time: 0.001s
sending 'persist' (4264 KB)...
OKAY [  0.390s]
writing 'persist'...
FAILED (remote: flash write failure)
Finished. total time: 0.655s
sending 'recovery' (8816 KB)...
OKAY [  0.805s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  1.536s]
Finished. total time: 2.342s
sending 'cache' (5304 KB)...
OKAY [  0.485s]
writing 'cache'...
OKAY [  1.376s]
Finished. total time: 1.861s
sending 'userdata' (36604 KB)...
OKAY [  3.339s]
writing 'userdata'...
FAILED (remote: flash write failure)
Finished. total time: 9.362s
sending 'usbmsc' (20480 KB)...
OKAY [  1.868s]
writing 'usbmsc'...
FAILED (remote: unknown partition name)
Finished. total time: 1.870s
Done...
rebooting...

Finished. total time: 0.001s
Just close the windows as you wish.
- waiting for device -
```

Please help.

Comment: You should be able to get into the recovery mode by removing the battery, and then starting the phone up by holding VOLUP/VOLDOWN/POWER. In the recovery menu there is probably an option to install firmware from the SD card. Put an official firmware on the SD card and recover from there.

Comment: I was able to do this before I did the above procedure. But now it just keeps rebooting. And it doesn

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to locate official images, ZTE had an eBay site with images based on country.  Whenever I soft brick a phone, I basically follow Jan's comment above to manually reboot the phone into the bootloader.  Once that's done, you should be able to see the phone manually from running `fastboot devices`.  Then the series of commands (that the flash scripts usually run) is simply:

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot flash system system.img
fastboot flash userdata userdata.img
fastboot reboot
```

I just did this today with Geeksphones peaks, but I've done it on almost every phone.